# AWS Lambda email function does not always send

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, email, aws-lambda

I have setup a custom flow with cognito to send MFA codes via email using lambda triggers. I have just noticed though that the function does not appear to always work and the emails are not always sent when requesting to login although the lambda metrics do not report any failures?

I have added some logs and checked in cloudwatch and the if statement to send the email is being hit and the sendEmail() method is executed but i dont see any email being sent in my inbox (i have checked the junk/spam)

My account is still in a sandbox mode but i havent hit my daily limits so quite confused what is going on.

Any ideas what is happening?

Here is a screenshot of the cloudwatch logs in an instance where no email was sent:

[image]

here is my lambda trigger below for sending emails:

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
var aws = require("aws-sdk");
var ses = new aws.SES({ region: "eu-west-2" });

exports.handler = async(event, context, callback) => {
    
    var verificationCode = 0;
   
    //Only called after SRP_A and PASSWORD_VERIFIER challenges.
    if (event.request.session.length == 2) {
        const n = crypto.randomInt(0, 100000);
        verificationCode = n.toString().padStart(6, "0");
        
        const minimumNumber = 0;
        const maximumNumber = 100000;
         
        verificationCode = Math.floor(Math.random() * maximumNumber) + minimumNumber;
        console.log('send email');
        console.log('verificationCode: '+ verificationCode);
        console.log('verificationCode: '+ event.request.userAttributes.email);

        const params = {
            Destination: { ToAddresses: [event.request.userAttributes.email] },
            Message: {
                Body: {
                    Html: {
                        Charset: 'UTF-8',
                        Data: `<html><body><p>This is your secret login code:</p>
                            <h3>${verificationCode}</h3></body></html>`
                    },
                    Text: {
                        Charset: 'UTF-8',
                        Data: `Your secret login code: ${verificationCode}`
                    }
                },
                Subject: {
                    Charset: 'UTF-8',
                    Data: 'Your secret login code'
                }
            },
            Source: 'my verified email address'
        };
        await ses.sendEmail(params).promise().then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
        });
    }
    else {
        //if the user makes a mistake, we pick code from the previous session instead of sending new code
        const previousChallenge = event.request.session.slice(-1)[0];
        verificationCode = previousChallenge.challengeMetadata;
    }
        
    //add to privateChallengeParameters, so verify auth lambda can read this. this is not sent to client.
    event.response.privateChallengeParameters = { "verificationCode": verificationCode };
    //add it to session, so its available during the next invocation.
    event.response.challengeMetadata = verificationCode;
    
    return event;
    };
```

Comment: If you have a reasonable idea of how many emails you think were sent by SES, you can cross-check this number against the Sending Statistics page in the SES Console.  If this number lines up with how many you think were sent but not with how many were actually received, there may be some email security in place, such as DKIM, which validates against the sender of the email.  I note that the code does have an 'else' block though so might be worth double-checking that it's not hitting that intermittently.

Comment: @Norman Thanks for the comment. Yeah just checked the SES dashboard for the count of successful email sends and this it does line up with how many i should have been sent. If i move out of sandbox will this fix the situation? I added some console in the first part of the if and its only ever hittting this when i check cloudwatch.

Comment: Is the recipient verified within the SES console?  I'm not 100% sure of the behaviour, but I imagine if it doesn't actually send the email it wouldn't be counted against the statistics, but this is something to verify in any case. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html

Comment: @Norman yeah I am sure i have setup everything correctly and my email is verified so struggling to see what is going on.

Comment: If you're certain that all emails were successfully sent, then perhaps there's an email security issue (SPF, DKIM, DMARC), relating specifically to the domain of the sender.

Comment: The verified email i am using is my own private one i.e example@hotmail.com so perhaps that has something to do with it